# How to create a role in a procedure in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl

I would like to know how I can create a role to a procedure in oracle. This procedure should (not globally) allow the user to Change the roles and delete them.

```
   create or replace PROCEDUR MY_ROLE(Name VARCHAR2) IS
   BEGIN
   DBMS_Output.put_line('You've got the right ' || Name );
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('grant some_role to Username' , Name);
   INSERT INTO FG7.ROLE values(Name);

   END MY_ROLE;
```

THanks!

Comment: You've included some code, but that's granting an existing role to a user (or trying to), while your question title and text is about creating a deleting roles. So do you have an issue with the code you've shown, and if so what? (The 'Username' shouldn't be there, and it's simpler to use the concatenation operator that the concat function...) Or are you asking us to write a new procedure for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper approach is to create a role, grant the role to user and then [SET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10004.htm#SQLRF01704) the ROLE:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SET ROLE '||some_role;
```

Use

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SET ROLE NONE';
```

to unset the role again. Of course when you grant the role to user it must not set as DEFAULT ROLE.

The issue with `GRANT some_role TO ...` is, it takes effect only after the user have been logged in again.

You can also use `DBMS_SESSION.SET_ROLE('some_role');` and `DBMS_SESSION.IS_ROLE_ENABLED('some_role')` to check whether a role is enabled. See [DBMS_SESSION.SET_ROLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sessio.htm#ARPLS68067)